# Xcode 8.2 cannot set entitlements membership

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-universal-links

I am trying to configure universal links on my App, but is not working. I read that a common cause of universal links are not working is that the entitlements file is not include in the build.

But I am not able to set the target membership of my entitlements (screenshot bellow), all the checkbox are disable.

[image]

Comment: I think you should open Capabilities Tab in Project Settings, and disable every setting there, then re-enable what you require, see if it works.

Comment: Add the entitlements file to Build Phases >> Copy Bundle Resources, Now membership must be in selected state :)

Comment: @Swati - I have the same problem as the original poster. You are correct that adding the entitlements file to the "Copy Bundle Resources" build phase does check the target membership box - however, it doesn't seem to resolve the problem. My app is still not launched when the user clicks on an associated link. Any suggestions?

Comment: Never mind - my problem seems to have been due to the use of a wildcard pattern in my domain. Using a literal subdomain instead of a wildcard resolved the problem.

Comment: Have You done Universal Link?
Please help me.

Answer (score 34):

As swati said in the comments.

Go to Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources. Click the plus sign then add your entitlement file.

The target membership will then show.